# How to parse a build.gradle file in java?

Tags: java, parsing, gradle, build.gradle

I need to parse the gradle build.gradle file in Java and list out all its dependencies(as List of Group:Artifact:Version) mentioned under dependencies block.

What would be the best possible solution for this?

build.gradle like below,

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.7.25'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.findbugs', name: 'annotations' , version: '3.0.0'
    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5"
    compile "org.owasp:dependency-check-gradle:4.0.1"
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.7'
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Gradle is Groovy in itself, you can call Java call from that. Why would you need to parse the build.gradle file?

Comment: my requirement is to scan a location and if any gradle project is found inside, show all the dependencies of the project in a json.scan logic is in java.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a custom gradle task to list all dependencies into a file.
2. Hook this task to the very beginning of build process.
3. Read that file from java